# jquery input-validation (number characters and decimal places)

Tags: jquery, validation

I have several javascript functions to validate the input data in textbox, so it will limit the user to type into the textbox a range of numbers (eg. from 0 to 500) an x amount of decimals (eg. 1 or 2 or 3 ....).

I am having some issues with the javascript functions because they are three separate functions and the alerts get a bit mixed up.

I was wondering if there is a jquery function that will make it neat, effective and simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Didn't realize you'd beat me to it :-) +1